# Where to set the value of CacheHelper.PhysicalFilesCacheMinutes?

Tags: c#, kentico

In Kentico cms performance settings, I already set the server cache and client cache time to more than 7 days but this property CacheHelper.PhysicalFilesCacheMinutes still returns 7 days. Sorry but I cant find the answer in kentico documentation so I really appreciates if someone knows the answer. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CacheHelper.PhysicalFilesCacheMinutes` equals to the `CMSPhysicalFilesCacheMinutes` appSetting in web.config. Its default value is 7 days. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/dosearchsite.action?where=K9&spaceSearch=true&queryString=CMSPhysicalFilesCacheMinutes).